# Proper use of the weather tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So on my question [here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/1592/527) I almost tagged it with weather when I wrote it but I decided not to because the question is about water levels in river which are not normally covered by weather sources. I almost used the water tag as well because that's what I was asking about but the description stopped me from doing so.

My question here is should weather be expanded to include things like water levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no hard-and-fast rule on how to tag questions. The purpose of tags is primarily to help future visitors find the answers they are looking for. So think to yourself how a future visitor might search for your question. In this case, their search might include "dry weather," so a weather tag could help them find it.

Also, don't take it personally if someone edits your questions, and especially your tags.

Comment: Oh, Not at all. That makes complete sense. I was more asking along the lines of "we both had this feeling is it correct?" Thanks for the answer.